# Как указать строку в регулярном выражении?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Например, есть текст:

```
|*Some Text1*|100
|*Some Text2*|200
|*Some Text3*|300
```

Как указать в регулярке, что мне нужно взять из первой строки число 100, или например из второй строки число 200 и из третей число 300? То есть все сразу значения после текста мне не нужны, но мне нужно три регулярки, которые в каждом случае возвращают именно число после символа | из строки 1 или строки 2 или из строки 3.

Answer (score 0):

Вам может помочь следующее регулярное выражение: `^\|[^|]*\|(\d+)`.

| Конструкция | Значение |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | Начало строки |
| `\|` | Символ `|` (его нужно экранировать) |
| `[^|]*` | 0 или более повторений любого символа, кроме `|` |
| `\d+` | 1 или более повторений цифры |

Группа для выбора указывается в круглых скобках: `(\d+)`.

---

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^\|[^|]*\|(\d+)')

num1 = regex.findall('|*Some Text1*|100')[0]  # 100
num2 = regex.findall('|*Some Text2*|200')[0]  # 200
num3 = regex.findall('|*Some Text3*|300')[0]  # 300
```

Comment: Почему-то на regexr.com у меня данное выражение получает в ответ, всю первую строку т.е. |*Some Text1*|100, а вот на regex101.com ответ корректный, хмм

Comment: @Nikita На сайте regexr.com перейдите на вкладку `Details` и увидите нужный [результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYzPm.png) в `Group 1`.

Comment: Спасибо, регулярка работает. Но если в нее передавать одну строку. Т.е. например: |*Some Text1*|100 А меня интересовало, как вытащить данные(цифры) у определенной строки, при условии что, это всё одна строка. Т.е. например, если я захочу вытащить данные из Some Text2, при том что, первой строкой у меня идет Some Text1, а третей строкой Some Text3, я не смогу этой регуляркой этого сделать. Я думал отличать строки символом \n но у меня не получается:(